# Check if a JavaScript Prompt was Closed/Cancelled

Tags: javascript, dom-events, silverlight-4.0

How to check using a If condition that a Prompt Box was cancelled or closed?
Am I supposed to check the `DetachEvent`?

I have to invoke this Prompt box again and again until the user explicitly Closes or Cancels the Box. I am coding on Silverlight..
My Prompt box looks  like this

```
dummyinput = System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage.Window.Invoke("prompt", new string[] { "Question", "Answer" }) as string;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldnt believe, that was so simple to track.. when you close / cancel the prompt, the value of the variable dummyinput becomes NULL.